# How to make Apache HTTP request from AsyncTask

Tags: android, http, post, android-asynctask

I am trying to get `json` values using `HTTP` `POST` method. So far I am able to receive values with `GET` method. And here is the code so far:

```
 private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Create Show ProgressBar
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)   {
        String result = "";
        try {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        //Log.w("PREMIERE::::",result);
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)  {
        // Dismiss ProgressBar
        showData(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Now assume if I have a field `number` with value=`+919061037828` , how do I adapt my code to get result in **POST** method?

This is how I call my `AsyncTask` :

```
public static final String URL = "https://api.eduknow.info/mobile/get_details";
new SimpleTask().execute(URL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is with parameters.

Try sth like this:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("your url");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",    "username"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", "en"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Hope it will help.

**EDIT** 
And I just found another possible solution for your problem:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request?rq=1)